# SQL Query that displays the number of athletes that have competed in at least ten different places(locations)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm building a query based on the fact that they have competed in ten or more places. Note that it does not matter how many sports or competitions they competed in, just how many places they have competed in.

```
CREATE TABLE Gender (
       gender CHAR(1),
       description VARCHAR(10),
       PRIMARY KEY (gender));

CREATE TABLE People (
       ID INT,
       name VARCHAR(50),
       gender CHAR(1),
       height FLOAT,
       PRIMARY KEY (ID),
       FOREIGN KEY (gender) REFERENCES Gender (gender));

CREATE TABLE Sports (
       ID INT,
       name VARCHAR(50),
       record FLOAT,
       PRIMARY KEY (ID),
       UNIQUE (name));

CREATE TABLE Competitions (
       ID INT,
       place VARCHAR(50),
       held DATE,
       PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE TABLE Results (
       peopleID INT NOT NULL,
       competitionID INT NOT NULL,
       sportID INT NOT NULL,
       result FLOAT,
       PRIMARY KEY (peopleID, competitionID, sportID),
       FOREIGN KEY (peopleID) REFERENCES People (ID),
       FOREIGN KEY (competitionID) REFERENCES Competitions (ID),
       FOREIGN KEY (sportID) REFERENCES Sports (ID));
```

If anyone can help me with this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure about postgrestsql, but check into these should have something similar, Group By, Having count >=10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1459036/brad), you can use a simple aggregated query that JOINs table People with Results, with a HAVING BY clause to filter on the number of competitions each person participated to. It seems like you don’t need to bring in any other table to achieve your goal.

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.Name
FROM
    People p
    Results r ON r.peopleID = p.ID
GROUP BY
    p.ID,
    p.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
```